# Pausing/Breaking execution in javascript for debugging, but only for certain javascript files

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, firebug, ie-developer-tools

Do any browsers support pausing execution / stepping through code, but only for certain files or regions? I'm using jQuery and several other libraries, and I'm not interested in stepping through their code in 99% of cases, as it is my code that is wrong. All my code is in my script file, other libraries are included separately.

If I use the pause button, I tend to find that I am very quickly taken to some part of jquery with code I don't understand or need to understand. If I click the step into button a lot, I sometimes get taken to a point in my script, sometimes not.

I could manually click every single line of my code to add a breakpoint, but this would be extremely tedious, and I couldn't un-pause execution easily. If there is a browser that lets you select multiple lines and add breakpoints to all of them in one click, that would be a great alternative, though.

Answer (score 2):

There are some new features in the [Chrome developer tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/scripts-breakpoints.html#listeners) that can help you get a good entry point into a new code base. Event listener breakpoints will let you pause execution at a given event handler:

Answer (score 1):

Things have changed since I asked the question 5 years ago. Chrome (and possibly other browsers) have an option "Blackbox script". If you find yourself paused inside a library, e.g. jQuery, right click, choose "Blackbox script" and you will automatically skip over all lines in that file when you are stepping through the code in future.

Answer (score 0):

This is what step in/over/out is for. If the program is stopped for debugging, and you're stepping through and see that you're about to descend into a jQuery function (or anything else you want to skip over) you click "step over".  If you got into something which you want to get right back out of, you click "step out".

Simply set the breakpoint where you want to begin debugging, and use the step functions from there to control what you're stopping to take a look at.

Comment: I don't know where I want to begin debugging. The problem is that I want to find which of my functions are being called by a particular event, either directly or via jQuery or other third party libraries. Also, I want to be able to click next without having to think "do I want to step into or over on this line". If a line is like `a = my_function() ? my_other_function() : third_party_function();` how do I know if I want to step in or over?

Comment: There is a fine line between "elegant" syntax and maintainable code. Seek balance.

Comment: I was just thinking of an example where it is impossible to know whether to press step in or step over to make the point that this is not always an easy choice to figure out. Setting the debugger to pause only in this file would be easy.

Comment: How in the world would the debugger know the difference between "your" code and a "third party's" code? What is a third-party anyway? Is it anyone other than you? Is it anyone other than the people on your team? Also, I'm really confused as to how you cannot know where you want to begin debugging. I think you have a much more fundamental problem than the use of the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Put the break points in the desired javascript files and where you want to inspect your code!
Press [image]  this will let you skip the jumping to other files and you will be able to continue in the same JS file

Comment: As I said in the last paragraph of the question, I can do this, but it would be extremely tedious to click hundreds of times in the debugger to set the break points. In my current project, 600 times. And I wouldn't be able to un-freeze execution, only to step from breakpoint to breakpoint.

Comment: Then You could put the break points at the desired places and then where you would like to jump first and then press the button before the `step over` button this will take you to the next break point you set...the putton is in `pause` when you are not debugging while debugging its `play` symbol

Comment: What desired places? I don't know what part of my code (well, my colleagues code) is being run. That's the whole problem.

Comment: Ahh...Tell you what rjmunro...Inspecting others code!!!...That itself is a tedious process....leave alone debugging it.... **Desired Place** = Where you think there is _probability_ that the code would be wrong and you might need to check it....